# How to get facebook page entire history in RSS XML or Json?

Tags: xml, facebook, import

I am trying to get an xml format for a facebook page but the problem is that it is limited to 29 items. To illustrate, say we go to https://www.facebook.com/barackobama and click the subscribe via rss https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=6815841748&format=rss20 (bottom left). It open an xml document with only 29 items. I would like to get more, and perhaps the entire history if possible. Let me know if you have any thoughts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a full JSON feed, just use https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/statuses?access_token=... (or /feed).  You can set the limit querystring parameter to get more values and if you still reach the Facebook limit, there will be next and prev URL's in the response to retrieve more values.  Try it with the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=cocacola/statuses?limit=50).

Comment: This actually works but getting an access token does not seem to persist over time; I believe it expires after a while. It also takes time to load especially if you are dealing with popular pages. So it is not efficient when I try to actually grab statuses every one hour through cron job. It is easier and more efficient, at least for me, to work with the "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=6815841748&format=rss20"  the only downside of this is the that it is limited to 20. Also, I have been trying to do this in a Drupal Platform, so any suggestions could be very helpful.

Comment: feeds/page.php not working since June 23, 2015. Is there any other way to get?