# Social media data provider

Tags: analytics, social-media

Today many companies are providing analytics based on social media data. In order to do that every company has to get the data from different social networks like twitter, facebook, etc. It would be nice if we could go to one single data provider that would provide us with data of all social networking sites. That way every company doesn't have to build their own data infrastructure and can concentrate on analytics only and not on data fetching. http://www.gnip.com is one such data provider. Does anyone know of any more such data providers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can actually think of quite a few data providers like that. Gnip is obviously the big kid in the room...but a few others are:

- http://www.datasift.com
- http://www.collectiveintellect.com
- http://www.spinn3r.com/ (Not as much of an all-encompassing aggregator, but should still work for the purposes you describe)

I'm sure there are others out there, but Gnip & these three (Datasift & Gnip in particular) seem like the biggest data providers of this sort.

Comment: Do DataSift or Gnip provide access to historical data from facebook?

Comment: As best I can tell, no - neither offer access to long-term historical data from Facebook. It appears the last 150 Facebook posts/updates are available from Gnip (unknown via DataSift), but besides that, neither mention anything about historic Facebook data. Twitter still seems to be the biggest/most open historical data provider for services like these - the rest seem to just provide current and recent data.

Comment: Thanks for the input..Do you know of any other provider who could provide it? Probably Facebook insights will include historical data? But I am looking only for raw data in jsons.

Comment: You might also check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343154/how-to-get-facebook-page-entire-history-in-rss-xml-or-json Not the most ideal solution, but seems like it would be a means to an end.